# return View(); does not work after FormsAuthentication.SignOut() have been executed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want user to be redirected to LogOff view upon click of a link, however based on some condition the logOff behavior is different. Following is the code in MVC4:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{

  FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

  if (<somecondition>)
  {
    return View();
  }
  else
  {
    return Redirect(<someURL>);
  }
}
```

Now, after "FormsAuthentication.SignOut()" if condition is true then return View is not working and throws error.
however, if condition is false then Redirect works as expected.

Question: Is it expected behavior that View will not work if we have sign out?

Thank you.

Comment: What error do you get when you use `return View();`.

Comment: The error is "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject'"

Comment: Is it possible that some kind of `ViewBag`/`ViewData` object isn't initialized when you return the View?

Comment: Nope, that redirection was at the end of the action, further there is no reference to any ViewBag or ViewData in view.

Comment: Perhaps you could paste the complete stack trace in your question and find out at which line it occurs.

Comment: yes, I did that. I added logging to figure-out where it is failing. That's the reason I am saying that View was failing and adding Redirect just worked.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you want to re-display the logout form again? And if you really have to, is there anything you have against redirecting to the logout page?

Comment: Good question. On log off, we want user to get redirect to another page, however if that does not work (redirection) then we display a message that "click here to redirect".

Comment: From my understanding, Forms authentication will restrict the access to other pages other than login page when u signout. Or else u have to override it in config.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am going to use "Redirect" instead of "View" as I don't want to play with web.config. I hope there wont be any drawbacks of it.

Comment: Redirect or view same should be the case I guess, So does it work for you now?

Comment: Yes, it is working. BTW: Is there any reference which can confirm that after signout return View will not work?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is expected behavior, if you want to override the `LogOff` view from authorization

Add this to your config file, give correct path to the View folder containing `LogOff` view.

```
  <location path="Views/LogOff">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand this. Why should I override? currently I am redirecting using "Redirect" method.